# How to create and access a shell config file from a shell script?

Tags: bash, file, shell, config

I am working on a shell script that when first opened asks the user for some info. This info needs to be stored on a config file for future use so that the user doesn't have to answer the same questions every time the program opens. Of course, I am planning on writing an if statement to check whether the info is in the config file every time the script is used, but I don't know how to create a config file. I would like to know how I can do this from the shell script itself, so that if a person downloads my script and uses it the config file is created for them. I would also like to know how I can add the info into the config file from the script. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution I often see is to write out a config file like this:

```
cat <<EOF > ~/.app/config
var1=$var1
var2=$var2
EOF
```

Then, that config file is a proper shell scrip itself, and can be sourced by the shell script at startup, like so:

```
[ -e ~/.app/config ] && source ~/.app/config
```

Sourcing it (rather than executing it as a command) ensures that all variables it defines will be visible in the script that sourced it.

Then, of course, you'd want to make user-directed customization after sourcing it, but before writing out the new version.

## Caveat Emptor

Using this method is okay for something quick-n-dirty, or something only you will touch. However, sourcing a script runs all of the code in it, in the current session. That means it can `rm -rf /`, and it could also redefine functions or variables which you've defined in your main script, overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some code like this:

```bsh
RC_PATH="~/.myscriptrc"
echo $var1 > $RC_PATH
echo $var2 >> $RC_PATH
```

`var1` and `var2` will be separated by a newline and stored in the `~/.myscriptrc` config file. So, given `var1=Foo` and `var2=Bar`, the  `~/.myscriptrc` file will be:

```
Foo
Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Again one OP that thinks that SO is its personal development center. You didn't even take the work to look at the other questions similar to his one, like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983558/reading-a-config-file-from-a-shell-script?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983558/reading-a-config-file-from-a-shell-script) and others.

Because you can run into serious troubles, I will recommend you a solution:

- search google for bash config file security

and you will find than **never** `source` any config variables, because it is dangerous. For example what happens when you `source` the next config file?

```
MAINPATH=/some/path/here;rm -rf / &
```

So, you should

- hardcode your app defaults in the code, and
- and when reading the config file you ***MUST*** ensure than the saved **values** doesn't contain any dangerous things (like above), so don't contain characters `;` or back-tick or `&` and like.  Best if it will contain only [A-Za-z0-9_/] and not others. This called as *sanitizing* config values.

The best you can do, using more powerful tool for config-file parsing, e.g. perl, awk or so.

And next time, use google or SO's search for getting answers **before asking here**

Ps: and sorry for the message, maybe i'm waked up in a bad mood, but starting get angry with OP's who didn't even try find a solution ourselves...

Comment: I did look for help on these topic and actually read many of the other questions asked about this, however, I did not find anything that was explained well enough or helped specifically my issue. Sorry if I got you mad for wanting more specific answers and thanks for the info.