# Shell command to retrieve specific value using pattern

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which contains data like below.

```
appid=TestApp
version=1.0.1
```

We want to parse the file and capture the value assigned to appid field.

I have tried with awk command as below

```
awk '/appid=/{print $1}' filename.txt
```

However it outputs the whole line

```
appid=TestApp
```

but we required only

```
TestApp
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this using awk/grep/sed shell commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the field separator:

```
awk -F'=' '$1 ~ /appid/ {print $2}' filename.txt
```

or with an exact match

```
awk -F'=' '$1 == "appid" {print $2}' filename.txt
```

outputs

```
TestApp
```

Comment: An exact match for this (`$1 == "appid"`) would probably be better than a pattern match.

Comment: @Jotne Any specific reason for that?

Comment: @EtanReisner It just shorter and simpler.

Comment: @Jotne I'd imagine costlier too, but ok.

Answer (score 3):

There's about 20 different ways to do this but it's usually a good idea when you have name = value statements in a file to simply build an array of those assignments and then just print whatever you care about using it's name, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
appid=TestApp
version=1.0.1
$
$ awk -F= '{a[$1]=$2} END{print a["appid"]}' file
TestApp
$ awk -F= '{a[$1]=$2} END{print a["version"]}' file
1.0.1
$ awk -F= '{a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) print i,"=",a[i]}' file
appid = TestApp
version = 1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the shell already then simply sourcing the file will let you get what you want.

```
. filename.txt
echo $appid
```

Comment: You should not recommend sourcing files, you never now what is hidden, see the explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260165)

Comment: Sourcing random files is certainly not safe. I wouldn't recommend using a file like that for user config either. But neither of those is the same as saying that in known processes one shouldn't source files.

Comment: Yes, that's also why I didn't downvote, because it probably works perfectly fine in this situation.

Comment: Right and a useful warning to add.